# Java error unable to identify mistake

Tags: java

This is Java code, I have created 4 classes 3 constructor and I am getting error of:

> method area in class Rect cannot be applied to given types

There is a similar error for rest of 2 class as well. In this program basically I have created 4 classes, 1 for calculating area of rect, 1 for calculating area of Tri and 1 for calculating area of Square and last one is to access main function.

I have created 3 constructor for all the 3 classes rect tri and square and I am unable to spot the mistake in this program.

```
class Rect    //1st class rect
{
    double l, b;   //variables

    Rect(double l, double b)     //constructor for rect 
    {
        this.l = l;
        this.b = b;
    }

    double area(double l, double b) //method to cal Rect area
    {
        return l * b;
    }
}

class Square   //square class
{
    double s;

    Square(Double s)   //constructor for class
    {
        this.s = s;
    }

    double area(double s) //method to cal area for square
    {
        return s * s;
    }
}

class Tri   // class for triangle 
{
    double l, b, h;   //variables

    Tri(double l, double b, double h)   // constructor for tri
    {
        this.l = l;
        this.h = h;
        this.b = b;
    }

    double area(double l, double b, double h) //method to cal area for tri
    {
        return 0.5 * l * b * h;
    }
}

class Area3 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Rect r = new Rect(10, 10);  //constructor initialization for Rect
        Square s = new Square(15.0);//constructor initialization for Square
        Tri t = new Tri(10.0, 20.0, 30.0);//constructor initialization for Tri
        System.out.print(" " + r.area() + "" + s.area() + "" + t.area()); //print areas
    }
}
```

Comment: Indent your code properly if you are asking people to try and read it.

Comment: "I've done everything correct" - that is evidently not the case.

Comment: The method `area` takes an argument (`double area(double s)`) and you're calling it without argument (`r.area()`).

Answer (score 1):

Your area method declarations state that the area methods take in arguments. With those declarations you can't say

```
Rect r = new Rect(1,4);
r.area();
```

Simply remove the double argument values from the area methods

Answer (score 0):

You have to create area method without parameters, here the solution,

```
 class Rect // 1st class rect
{
    double l, b; // variables

    Rect(double l, double b) // constructor for rect
    {
        this.l = l;
        this.b = b;
    }

    double area(){
        return this.l * this.b;
    }

    double area(double l, double b) // method to cal Rect area
    {
        return l * b;
    }
}

class Square // square class
{
    double s;

    Square(Double s) // constructor for class
    {
        this.s = s;
    }

    double area(){
        return this.s * this.s;
    }

    double area(double s) // method to cal area for square
    {
        return s * s;
    }
}

class Tri // class for triangle
{
    double l, b, h; // variables

    Tri(double l, double b, double h) // constructor for tri
    {
        this.l = l;
        this.h = h;
        this.b = b;
    }


    double area(){
        return 0.5 * this.l * this.b * this.h;
    }

    double area(double l, double b, double h) // method to cal area for tri
    {
        return 0.5 * l * b * h;
    }
}

class Area3 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Rect r = new Rect(10, 10); // constructor initialization for Rect
        Square s = new Square(15.0);// constructor initialization for Square
        Tri t = new Tri(10.0, 20.0, 30.0);// constructor initialization for Tri
        System.out.print(" " + r.area() + " and " + s.area() + " and " + t.area()); // print
                                                                        // areas
    }
}
```

Hope this help, BTW it's work in my PC.

Answer (score 0):

look at your contractors, they all receive an arguments.
and all your area()'s are getting also a arguments.

but!! in your main, you are calling the area() and do not give any values.

just delete from area()'s functions the receiving arguments.